# Facebook graph api json_decode error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, json

Playing around with the Facebook Graph API and the Facebook PHP SDK.  Having a problem using **json_decode()**, I keep getting the error "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string".

```
if ($fbme) {
        try {
            $pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
        }
        catch(Exception $o) {
            d($o);
        }
}


$pages = json_decode($pages, true);
        foreach ($pages->data as $page) {
            echo $page->name;
            echo $page->category;
            echo $page->id;
        }
```

Comment: Well, what does `$pages` contain?

Comment: When I echo out $pages it just outputs "Array" when I use print_r($pages) I get Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Company Name [category] => Professional_services [id] => 150568998319 [access_token] => ) ) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `api` method already decodes the response for you. You don't have to use `json_decode` on it, since it's already an array.

```
foreach ($pages['data'] as $page) {
    echo $page['name'];
    echo $page['category'];
    echo $page['id'];
}
```

Comment: I tried that first time around, or at least I thought so, it was giving me a foreach error, works now, THANKS :)